# hybrid web/client framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax, database

I am developing a web app that will be used by individuals in various locations.  There is a relatively small mysql database on my server.  The thing is at times the users may not have internet access.  Is there some sort of hybrid framework/language that I could use in this case.

To be more clear, the program needs to do some fairly rigorous calculations and it needs to fetch values from my mysql database.  I can solve this problem using php and mysql.  The problem is what happens when they do not have connectivity?

A fine solution is they could download a local copy of the database in the morning while traveling (what are some good light weight DBMSs in this case?) Then they need a client based program (javascript?).

I'd like to reuse code for both instances which rules out php.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Modern browsers have support for localStorage, the ability to save data offline. You can access this using JavaScript.  If you use GMail on a smart phone for example, it will let you read cached messages if you are not connected.  However, you have to worry about syncing back to the server at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML 5 have local storage (like database) and you can use in this case. But not every browser support that now. 
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: One import gotcha (besides no sql support) is that browsers by default limit the amount of data you can store per site.  I think it something like 5MB.